# Array does not remove all elements

Tags: php, arrays, json

```
$channels = array('imaqtpies','imsoff','zzero71tv', 'kaptenen', 'onlySinged', 'nightblue3') ;
$nr = 0;


$callAPI = implode(",",$channels);
$online = 'online.png';     
$offline = 'offline.png';   
$json = file_get_contents('https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/streams?channel=' .     $callAPI);
$dataArray = json_decode($json, true);

foreach($dataArray['streams'] as $mydata){
    echo $mydata['channel']['name'] . ' is online';
    echo '<br /><hr />';
    unset($channels[$nr]);
    $nr++;
}

$newChannels = array_values($channels);;


foreach($newChannels as $channel) {
    echo $channel . ' is offline';
    echo '<br /><hr />';
}
```

Not all the names are echoed in the "offline" part and some names are being echoed twice (both in online and offline).

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$mydata['channel']['name']` and `$nr` are not aligned. You're unsetting the first *x* channels but I don't see why twitch should return them in the order you've defined your channels.

You will want something like:

```
$online_channels = array();
foreach($dataArray['streams'] as $stream){
    $online_channels[] = $stream["channel"]["name"];
}
$offline_channels = array_diff($channels, $online_channels);
```

Then print `$online_channels` and `$offline_channels`.